# I need to calculate the percentage of the target and display

Tags: python, django

I do app on Django, just learning, to be exact, and I had a problem, I do to do list, which has a goal and each goal there are steps to achieve this goal, there can be an unlimited number. well, I need to calculate the percentage of the target and display, ie to take count kollichesvo performed (already implemented) and divided by the total of the stages. here's the problem.

**Model:**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(
            default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(
            blank=True, null=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
class Stage(models.Model):
    keys = models.ForeignKey(Post)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(
            default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField()
    end = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    procent = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**views**

```
def post_detail(request, pk):

    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    posts = Stage.objects.filter(keys__exact=pk,)        
    return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', {'post': post, 'posts': posts})
```

**this example**

```
x = len(posts)
for m in posts:
    if end == True:
        ar = ar + 1

stages = (ar / x * 100)
```

Comment: what is target and display ? What exactly are you trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a method to your class:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    # ...
    def percentage_complete(self):
        total = self.stage_set.count()
        completed = self.stage_set.filter(end=True).count()
        return (float(completed) / total) * 100
```

And in your template, assuming you have a `post` context variable:

```
% done: {{ post.percentage_complete }}
```